# What traits are available in the game, and what does each of them do?

Tags: rogue-legacy

There seems to be a good amount of traits in this game, and some of them don't have description that actually lets you know what that trait does.

For the sake of proper answer write down all traits available in the game, their description, and their effect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Good

- **ADHD**: Increased movement speed.
- **Eidetic Memory**:The last known location of enemies is shown on the map.
- **O.C.D.**: Breaking items will restore 1MP each.
- **P.A.D.**: Peripheral Arterial Disease. Your legs have no pulse, so you do not trigger spike traps.

## Bad

- **Alzheimers**: Means that your Map is replaced by ???, strangly your Mini-Map in the top right-hand corner is unnafected by this and will remain unchanged [Not known if this intentional or unintentional].
- **C.I.P.**: Congenital Insensitivity to pain. Health bar is no longer visible.
- **Color-Blindness**: Means that your screen is in Grey, White or Black. This can be confusing as backrounds can blend with enemies.
- **Dementia**: The player will occasionally see enemies that do not exist. They cannot be damaged, and cannot damage the player.
- **Dyslexia**: Scrambles letters in text.
- **Farsighted**: Everything nearby is blurry.
- **Hypochondriac**: Damage shows as considerably higher than it actually is.
- **Nearsighted**: Everything far away is blurry.
- **Nostalgic**: Sepia-tones the game. The loading screen will also say "Reminiscing" instead of "Building"
- **Stero-Blindness**: Means every enemy and your self do not have sides and will look like a flattened version of themself when turning sideways. (Can reduce visibility of mage enemies in some cases.)
- **Tunnel Vision**: No peripheral vision. When enemy projectiles are fired outside the player screen range, they won't show up in the borders of the screen as they usually do.
- **Vertigo**: Welcome to Barfs-ville. (Everything on the screen is upside down)

## Could be Good or Bad

- **Alektorphobia**: The drumsticks that normally drop will instead run around and attack you. Once killed, they will heal you as normal.
- **Ambilevous**: Any spells will go the opposite horizontal direction from their normal direction.
- **Dextrocardia**: Your HP and MP pools are swapped. Who knew? (HP and MP swapped)
- **Dwarfism**: Makes you incredibly small and gives you an advantage as you can access most secrets in the game, but you will have a much smaller swing range.
- **E.D.S**: You are very flexible. Allows you to turn around while swinging your weapon.
- **Ectomorph**: Increases knockback caused by enemies.
- **Endomorph**: No knockback caused by enemies.
- **Gigantism**: Makes you incredibly large, this can be bad as your hitbox is much bigger but also good as your swing range is much much large giving an advantage against enemies with less range.
- **Hypergonadism**: Greatly increases knockback caused to enemies.
- **Muscle Weakness**: Enemies don't get knocked back.
- **Savant**: Each time you use your spell, it changes to a different one.

## Cosmetic

- **Baldness**: Makes you bald, hence having no feathers on the helmet. Also makes the loading screen for the Castle say Balding instead of Building.
- **Coprolalia**: %#&@! (You swear when you are hit, your last words are always punctuation)
- **Gay**: No effect, bar reversing which statue (knight or lady) grants the chicken leg or mana potion in waypoint rooms.
- **I.B.S**: Stands for Irritable Bowel Syndrome and all it does is make you fart and leave a cloud behind when you jump.

Comment: Yes, I'm still adding more. As soon as I posted it I really it was very incomplete.

Comment: You missed "Tourettes" which was also on the wiki. Anyway that's 13 of them. From what i heard there is around 30 of them in total. Keep adding them to the list as you go, once you have all of them here I'll accept the answer, unless someone else beats you to it.

Oh btw, you should leave space between each trait info so they're easier to read.

Comment: Wups, Tourettes was there, I just missed it when I was adding bullets.

Comment: This game sounds so silly.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja It is incredibly silly, and incredibly awesome.

Comment: So, do Hypogonadism and Muscle Weakness actually do the same thing? That seems surprising, because they would be the only such pair, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain Hypogonadism exists. Apparently it's listed in the demo, but I can't recall having seen it, and the name may have changed since the demo, due to the similarity between Hypogonadism and Hypergonadism

Comment: With a new patch Tourettes got renamed to Coprolalia. It still does exactly the same thing though.

Comment: Oh, okay. I wondered that it had the same description. I'm also going to go ahead and get rid of Hypogonadism.

Comment: I organized your list, feel free to undo if you don't like it

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Oh, thank you! I kept meaning to do that, but never got around to it. I moved Alektorphobia to "Could be good or bad", as I think it is a very good trait.

Comment: I believe **Alektorphobia** is technically **bad**, since you can now receive damage from a healing item.

Comment: Gay will also change the end cinematic, I believe.  And @MarkRogers it can also be good, because it allows you to 'save' that healing item in that room for later if you don't need it right away.

Answer (score 2):

Also, to add to the full list, from some play testing it seems that certain traits will trigger the giant painting versions of the Doomvas in some of the special rooms.

I only ever triggered the painting with the odd looking female in it when I was a character that was attracted to females, and one of the black and white ones was only ever triggered when I had color-blindness.

These may be coincidence, but so far I've been able to predict some of them based on these relationships.

Comment: This would be very interesting if it could be confirmed. I'll keep an eye out in my own games.