# Why is this unit randomly invulnerable?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I have never seen this unit be invulnerable before, but now my sword goes right through this enemy without doing any damage. Question mark symbols float above the unit after my attack.

[image: Screenshot]

What's going on?

---

Edit: It happened again, this time with a different unit. I also noticed that it doesn't damage me:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are seeing things. You should check what your doctor diagnosed you with :)

Comment: And the map's not working either!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is an effect of the Dementia trait. Occasionally you will encounter an enemy that is only in your head.

See my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122071/what-traits-are-available-in-the-game-and-what-does-each-of-them-do/122075#122075) for a full list of traits.

Comment: @Codemonkey Would you mind accepting this, if it helped you? It's been bugging me that one of my highest voted answers remains unaccepted :P

Answer (score -3):

You probably had the dementia trait which makes you insane so you see fake enemies which dont harm you neither can you kill them

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the existing answer. Please don't add a new answer unless you have something significant to add.