# In Rogue Legacy how does your character being gay effect you

Tags: rogue-legacy

All I could find is that the genders of statues are reversed if your character/child in Rogue Legacy is gay. Is this really all that happens or is there any kind of additional trade off (benefit/loss) of any kind?

I only found an answer in Wiki so I wanted to double check this.

Comment: This has been answered here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/122075/41309

Comment: Yup that answers it. Thx for the quick follow-up. Sorry too - searched for it, but searching for this topic individually didn't help... searching for the term "traits" worked.

Comment: No need to apologize! Duplicate questions are [not bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: Ok cool - good to know :)